# Starting service (jar) in Linux on system boot fails but jar itself is working (where is my nohup.out?)

Tags: linux, service, jar, systemd

I try to get my jar-file running on system boot using systemd service with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description = Java Service
After network.target = JKHubServerService.service

[Service]
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/JKHubServerService.sh start
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/JKHubServerService.sh stop
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/JKHubServerService.sh reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=JKHubServerService
PATH_TO_JAR=/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/JKHub/dist/JKHub.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/JKHubServerService-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR >> myService.out 2>&1&
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR >> myService.out 2>&1&
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Nothing I desire happens on startup (should create database and listen for incoming connection on a specified port) and when I try and start the service (which is enabled) manually with

```
sudo systemctl start JKHubServerService
```

the following output is generated:

```
Job for JKHubServerService.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status JKHubServerService.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

followed by:

```
● JKHubServerService.service - Java Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/JKHubServerService.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-12-21 13:19:44 GMT; 11s ago
    Process: 731 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/JKHubServerService.sh start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 7ms

Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[731]: JKHubServerService.service: Failed to execute /usr/local/bin/JKHubServerService.>
Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[1]: Starting Java Service...
Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[731]: JKHubServerService.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/JKHubSer>
Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[1]: JKHubServerService.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[1]: JKHubServerService.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 21 13:19:44 JKHub systemd[1]: Failed to start Java Service.
```

when status is checked.

However, I can run the jar file manually when logged in as "pi" like "java -jar JKHub.jar" and also like "JKHubServerService.sh start" when loggen in as "root"

Somehow I suspect the jar not being able to generate folders/files or failing due to some wonky paths!? But I can't confirm any of that because I cannot find any output files when starting the service.

Where would they be? (I used both `nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &` and `nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR >> myService.out 2>&1&` as suggested [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example)

Sorry for the lengthy question but since I am very unexperienced in using linux and being stuck for days now I kindly ask for some help of you smart people!

Comment: Looks like it is running as root.  Is java in root's PATH?  Is the rest of the environment set properly for root?

Comment: how do I make sure java is in root's PATH?
I just added JAVA_HOME to root's /usr/environment file (as suggested by some other site) to no avail tho.

Comment: Why are you running the service as root?  Do you need to?  Why would you mess up root's environment for one program?

Comment: what would be the proper way to do it then?
I have no clue how to run my jar file on startup and just followed instructions I found on the internet!

Comment: Run it either as yourself, or as a user created for the purpose with proper environment settings.

Comment: how is that done when nobody logs in?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363098/running-a-systemd-service-as-a-user-other-than-root

Comment: Thank you very much good sir! I will do it like that.
And btw: my Problem was a stupid extra new line at the start of my script -.-
Feeling dumb now...